# Help evaluate $\int_{-L}^{L} \cos(\frac{nπx}L)\cos(\frac{mπx}L)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $m$  and $n$  be tow integers.

$$\int_{-L}^{L} \cos\left(\frac{nπx}L\right)\cos\left(\frac{mπx}L\right)dx = \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{$n \neq m$} \\
L, & \text{$n = m \neq 0$} \\
2L, & \text{$n = m = 0$}
\end{cases}  $$

Please show me how calculate step-by-step.

Thanks.

Comment: What is $\cos (\alpha + \beta) + \cos (\alpha - \beta)$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** use
$$
\cos A \cos B = \frac 12\left[
\cos(A+B)+\cos(A-B)
\right]
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since the function is an even function, and its integration limits are from -L to L, you can change the integral to:
$$2 \int_0^L \cos({n \pi x \over L})\cos({m \pi x \over L}) \, dx$$

Then use the identity $ \, \cos A\cos B= \frac 12 (\cos(A-B)+\cos(A+B))$ to get

$$2 \int_0^L \cos({n \pi x \over L})\cos({m \pi x \over L}) \, dx = \int_0^L \cos{(m-n) \pi x \over L}dx + \int_0^L \cos{(m+n) \pi x \over L}dx$$

Integration of cosine function is a sine function.

$$ \int \cos({n \pi x \over L})dx= {L \over n\pi} \sin({n \pi x \over L})\, + \, constant$$